# python web scraping - len(containers) always returning 0

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

i am trying to web-scrape pokemon information from their [online pokedex](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/), but i'm having trouble with the `findAll()`function. i've got:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"pokemon-info"})
```

but I'm not sure if this `div` is where i need to be looking at all, because (see photo [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUHI.png)) this `div` is inside a `li`, so perhaps i should search within it instead, like so:

```
 containers = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"animating"})
```

but in both cases when i use `len(containers)`, the length returned is always 0, even though there are several entries.

i also tried `find_all()`, but the results of `len()` are the same.

Comment: open web browser, turn off JavaScript and load your url. And you will see what BS can see. Page uses JavaScript to load data and BS can't run JavaScript. You need Selenium to control web browser which will load url and run JavaScript and after that you can get HTML from Selenium to BS or use function in Selenium to search elements (click buttons, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BeautifulSoup can't read javascript. As furas said, you should open the webpage and turn off javascript ([here's how](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000891.htm)) and then see if you can still access what you want. If you can't, you need to use something like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to control the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As the other comments and answer suggested, the site is loading the data in the background. The most common response to this is to use Selenium; my approach is to first check for any API calls in Chrome. Luckily for us, the page retrieves 953 pokemon on load.

Below is a script that will retrieve the clean JSON data and [here](https://medium.com/@adamwilliamson_51309/python-stop-using-selenium-859b6e0bf662) is a little article I wrote explaining the use of chrome developer tools in the first instance over Selenium.

```
# Gotta catch em all

import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {

    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer': 'https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

r = requests.get('https://www.pokemon.com/us/api/pokedex/kalos', headers=headers)
j = r.json()

print(j[0])
```